# QGIS automatically open a corporate basemap

Tags: qgis, basemap

We are looking at installing QGIS across the team using OS APIs as a standard basemap.

Is it possible so when users open a new project in QGIS they have the api basemap as standard and focused on a specific area of interest.

I know this is possible in ArcGIS Pro but can the same be achieved in QGIS?

Comment: I think you can achieve your goal by creating python script that loads these layers into layer tree and enabling this code to run on every QGIS startup.
The only thing I'm not sure is if you can execute any code with opening QGIS app or only with loading certain project to opened app. I can't check right now.

Comment: In AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3 there is a startup.py file (or can be created there) which runs when QGIS starts. You could use it to load layers into the canvas. There will probably need to be some tests (only add the layer if it isnt there already, or when it is a new project). And then you need a way to push the startup.py file to every users hardrive, plus handle the new file version scenario. There might be better options though. Maybe Comrade Che's solutions suits better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a QGIS project and set any content (including print layouts) into it.

There is an option in the settings that allows you to automatically load the custom default project on launch: `Options` => `General` => `Open project on launch`.

However, there is still a question to me - how to apply this option when installing QGIS. Apparently, it is necessary to run some script that will install QGIS and set this option automatically.

[image]